# Audioworks from powershell:

Tags: powershell, aac

I am using the [audioworks](https://github.com/jherby2k/AudioWorks) module for powershell, and believe I am using it per the docs.

When I open the aac file in vlc, I see it is aac in Media properties.

But Audioworks gags on the file:

```
PS C:\temp\test> Get-AudioFile in.aac
Get-AudioFile : Unable to decode 'C:\temp\test\in.aac' with any loaded extension.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AudioFile in.aac
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (in.aac:String) [Get-AudioFile], AudioUnsupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AudioUnsupportedException,AudioWorks.Commands.GetAudioFileCommand
```

Ahhh, because even though the docs indicate aac is supported, there appears not to be a module installed to support it...

```
 Get-AudioEncoderInfo

Name    Description
----    -----------
FLAC    Free Lossless Audio Codec
LameMP3 Lame MPEG Audio Layer 3
Opus    Opus
Vorbis  Ogg Vorbis
Wave    Waveform Audio File Format
```

I will try to contact the developer.

**UPDATE AND CONCLUSION**

OK, I see in the docs that to get AAC support requires the installation of iTunes.

For a normal windows setup, that is a ton of overhead to support one codec. (My whole agenda is to lose my dependence on VLC... if I simply inherit a dependence on iTunes I have not gained much... in fact, iTunes puts so much stuff on a Windows system that it is a step backward from VLC.)

Deeply bummed that AudioWorks has this external dependency for a codec that is central to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to **AAC support**, the [docs](https://github.com/jherby2k/AudioWorks) state under **requirements on Windows** (emphasis added):

> **[iTunes](https://www.apple.com/itunes)** (*optional, for AAC and ALAC support*. *Requires the **classic installer***, not the Windows Store version)

Comment: Ohhhh, I will look there. (Ouch, all of iTunes just to get aac support... that is brutal. That probably negates the utility of this powershell library (for me).